# Shell bash used in a roslaunch[SOLVED]

Tags: ros, roslaunch, shell, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am having a problem when trying to execute a comand from a roslaunch file which I dont have when running it directly from the shell.

When I execute `rosbag play *.bag` from the shell it plays every rosbag in the folder.

However when I do the following from a roslaunch file

```
<arg name="path" default="/home/kailegh/Descargas/Custom/20Jul16/" /> 
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="player" output="screen" args="--clock  $(arg path)*.bag">
</node>
```

It does not work, I obtain the following error

```
[ INFO] [1475572463.796418638]: Opening /home/kailegh/Descargas/Custom/20Jul16/*.bag
[FATAL] [1475572463.796604618]: Error opening file: /home/kailegh/Descargas/Custom/20Jul16/*.bag
```

I think the problem is that the roslaunch interpret the * as a normal character, instead of the bash meaning everything.
Is there any way to use the '*' in a launch file as it where in the command line?

Thanks a lot from your help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244960/shell-bash-used-in-a-roslaunch%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-10-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In its current form, I don't believe that `roslaunch` will support this behavior. The `roslaunch` command line script parses the launch files to figure out arguments, and then eventually opens new subprocesses using the Python `subprocess.Popen` function. Here are the [relevant lines of code](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/08f6bf06fe4e68efbf6b2c13b558a4d5298d1a41/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py#L297-L305). There are many questions online about how to have Popen support globbing (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997048/python-subprocess-wildcard-usage)), and the general consensus is that you need to have `shell=True` (which is often not a good idea... check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)). The relevant lines in `roslaunch` don't set `shell=True` (and they probably shouldn't), and therefore the globbing feature (which is specific to your shell... likely bash) doesn't work.

You could write a simple bash script that handles the globbing for you. For example a starting point would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
rosbag play --clock $1
```

Then your launch file could be changed to

```
<launch>
  <arg name="path" default="/home/kailegh/Descargas/Custom/20Jul16/" /> 
  <node pkg="your-package" type="name-of-bash-script.sh" name="player" output="screen" args="$(arg path)*.bag" />
</launch>
```

This could give your the functionality that you want.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-10-05**:
thanks man,l had thought using a bash script, but what I had in mind was a lot more complicated, that is the perfect solution. **Thanks a lot again, problem solved.**